# Dynamically array input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to input the amount of array and the output will follow as it's amount.
Ex: If I put "7" in the input text. the result will show as much as 7.
Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript - Input Text Field</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="test">
<H2>Enter something into the field and press the button. <br></H2>
<P>Amount of Tables: <input type="TEXT" name="amount"><BR><BR>
<input type="Button" Value="Show and Clear Input" onClick="myFunction()"></P>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
     var text = "";
     var i;
     var j = document.getElementsByName("amount");
     for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
           text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
     }
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are you trying this: `function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var i;
  var j = document.getElementsByName("amount")[0];
  for (i = 0; i < parseFloat(j.value); i++) {
   text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
 }`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You have something wrong on your JavaScript

See code:

```
function myFunction() {
     var text = "";
     var i;
     var j = document.getElementsByName("amount")[0];

     for (i = 0; i < j.value; i++) {
           text += "The number is " + j.value + "<br>";
     }
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

`.getElementsByName` returns an array of elements, so you need to specify the index of your element so that you can access its properties.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ohcrngo/)